# get_post_meta with WP_query

Tags: query, meta-query, post-meta

I know this is a convoluted loop (inherited from someone else), and this must be pretty simple: `the_permalink` and `the_title` display OK, but why doesn't my post meta `eventdatestart` echo?.

```
<?php
$queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=events&posts_per_page=5' );
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
?>
<div id="wrapper"">                  
    <h3>Events</h3>
    <ul>
        <?php
    while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        $queryObject->the_post();
        ?>
        <li>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'eventdatestart', true );?>

        </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </ul>
</div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe because of this part: `echo =` ? I sometimes do that mistake when I'm in a hurry ;-)

Comment: Arg, you're right, but that didn't make a difference. There's something not working globally with the post ID, I think.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but is `eventdatestart` the correct meta key? Does it really exists or maybe it's an array?

Comment: It's the correct key, for one key, not an array.

Comment: If you think the post ID does not work in your case, can you simply echo that? Then check for `eventdatestart` meta key for that specific post id in the database.

Comment: I'm assuming `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` return properly?

Comment: Stephen, good point, yes they do....

Comment: Can you var_dump($queryObject) and share the results? It might help to see what is returned in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to add `global $post` after the loop starts based on a similar [question found here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-wordpress-wp_query-return-custom-field-post-meta).

```
<?php
while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
   $queryObject->the_post();
   global $post;
?>
```

I wish I could explain more about why, but I didn't have time to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the ID is correct? try echoing `get_the_ID()`.

If that is the issue, maybe try `$queryObject->post->ID`. If that works, you could set it as a variable and use within get_the_ID, like this:

```
$myID = $queryObject->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID($myID), 'eventdatestart', true );
```

Comment: Hmmm... `get_the_ID()` doesn't echo anything.

Comment: Did you try echoing $queryObject->post->ID - does that worK?